# How to use NinjectModule with Ninject.MVC and multiple layers?

Tags: ninject

I have four layers in my application where the Service layer is the context root:

```
Presention
    |
    |
Services (Context Root)
    |
    |
Repository
    |
    |
Data
```

I am using Ninject MVC for the Presention layer specific items, and I have everything else registered in the services layer (context root).
However, My data layer has some data layer specific services that I would like registered in that layer. Currently my Services layer doesn't know about my Data layer and I see no real reason to make that a requirement. Is there a way using Ninject Modules to register all IOC containers that inherit from Ninject Module in one fell swoop?

On a side note I am using Telerik in the project so I cannot use reflection to get all of the objects that inherit from NinjectModule. Telerik's versions of NinjectModule are either sealed or unable to be accessed and re-registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Ninject IKernel interface has a Load() method which takes as parameter a list of assemblies. It will search for any INinjectModule in those assemblies and load them.

otherwise, check out the [Ninject Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) project. I am using it to automatically bind any class that implements my own `IDependency`:

```
        Kernel.Bind( scanner =>
        {
            scanner.From( assemblies )
                .Select( t => t.Is<IDependency>() )
                .BindAllInterfaces()
                .ConfigureFor<ISingletonDependency>( config => config.InSingletonScope() )
                .ConfigureFor<IRequestDependency>( config => config.InRequestScope() );
        } );
```